# Multiple logos in header with long navigation

Tags: header

I currently have the following header:
[image]
The general idea here is we have the main website logo, but because we're offering this website to company partners to use they want to add their own logo - in this case the circular icon to the right of the website logo.

This is fine on larger screens as there is plenty of space to fit the two logos plus the long navigation on the right. However as we start to move towards smaller laptop screen sizes there isn't enough room, especially for longer partner logos. At about 1000 pixels we do switch to a hamburger menu for the navigation but there's a couple hundred pixel screen size where this doesn't work.

What are some options for solving this? I can make the logos smaller and remove the Feedback text when it reaches a certain breakpoint but wondered if there were any smarter ideas. Thanks.

Comment: What does it look like in that couple hundred pixel range where it "doesn't work?" Could you not change your code to switch the hamburger menu sooner if necessary? Or is it that you're wanting to avoid the hamburger menu and are looking for other options?

Comment: Is showing the main provider logo bigger in the footer an option for you? Like "powered by" ones? Or are you a partner of the labeling company, not the provider of the service?

Answer (score -1):

The hamburger menu is the only clean way to solve this problem; you can customize your code to fit the logo. 
When clicking on the hamburger menu button a drop down menu or a slider from left appears showing your logo on top, and then the rest of the items below it.